# Jest Unit Testing - how to unit test if/else condition and call method based on true/false inside jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I started learning Jest framework. Would like to write test case for following method

```
const valueCheck() =  () => {
if (typeof (props.user.value != undefined) && props.user.value){
    callResult([]);
} else{
   notification.warn(['Wrong value']);
 }
}
```

Not sure how to do that. Please help I am not able to figure this out

Comment: You'll need to give more context.  Presumably `props`, `callResult`, and `notification` are defined somewhere in your code so that they're available to this method?  It will be much easier to test if you pass these things in explicitly rather than relying on the outer scope to supply them.

Comment: callResult([]) is called with blank array

Answer (score 1):

you need to test if `callResult()` or a `notification.warn` was called when you call `valueCheck()`

To do this you must use a [spy function](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) for `valueCheck` and `notification`

Also ,our syntax is incorrect and it can be simplified in a one line arrow function:

```js
const valueCheck = () => props?.user?.value ? callResult() : notification.warn(['Wrong value'])
```

Comment: How to write the test case can you please tell me here.